# Correctly removing control from FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I correctly dispose an user control in a FlowLayoutPanel ?

Does `flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.RemoveAt(i)` suffice?

I just can't find a .Dispose() for `flowlayoutpanel1.Controls`...

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to remove all the controls, you can iterate through the control collection backwards, rather than creating a copy (see below).

I have found this provides the best solution, particularly if you intend to re-populate it afterwards.  Forcing GC to collect helps keep memory use in check where there are a large number of controls.

```
FlowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();

if (FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count > 0) {
    for (int i = (FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        Control c = FlowLayoutPanel.Controls[i];
        c.SomeEvent -= SomeEvent_Handler;
        c.Dispose();
    }
    GC.Collect();
}

FlowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to dispose all the controls in the `FlowLayoutPanel` or all of them? If you want to dispose all of them, just dispose the `FlowLayoutPanel`. Disposing a control disposes everything in the Controls collection as well. If you want to dispose an individual control, call that control's Dispose method; the `FlowLayoutPanel` will automatically remove it from its Controls collection.

If you want to dispose all the controls, but not the `FlowLayoutPanel` itself, it's a bit trickier. You can't just foreach over the Controls collection and dispose each control because that would cause the Controls collection to be modified. Instead, you could copy the Controls collection to a separate list and dispose of them from there.

Comment: i need to dispose only one control ( the first one )

Answer (score 0):

If the control has `Dispose()` method just call it after removing it from the panel.